# Voronoi diagram: what is output of [v,C] = voronoin(X) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, voronoi

I have an image and I want to generate its voronoi diagram
V = {V_1,V_2,...,V_N} in MATLAB and take corner points of image as seed points and V_i is set of pixels.I used

```
[v,C] = voronoin(corners);
```

I know that C is vooronoi cells but Are these cells contain location of pixels?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoin.html):

> V is a numv-by-n array of the numv Voronoi vertices in n-dimensional space, each row corresponds to a Voronoi vertex. **C is a vector cell array where each element contains the indices into V of the vertices of the corresponding Voronoi cell.**

It means `C` is created based on vertices in `V` and mentioned id  of the vertices for each cell.

For example:

```
X = [0.5 0; 0 0.5; -0.5 -0.5; -0.2 -0.1; -0.1 0.1; 0.1 -0.1; 0.1 0.1]

X = 

     0.5000         0
     0    0.5000
    -0.5000   -0.5000
    -0.2000   -0.1000
    -0.1000    0.1000
     0.1000   -0.1000
     0.1000    0.1000
```

Compute the voronoi cell:

```
[V,C] = voronoin(X)

 V = 

   Inf       Inf
 0.7000   -1.6500
-0.0500   -0.0500
-0.0500   -0.5250
-1.4500    0.6500
-1.7500    0.7500
      0    0.2875
 0.3833    0.3833
 0.2875         0
      0         0

C = 7×1 cell array
[1×4 double]
[1×5 double]
[1×4 double]
[1×4 double]
[1×4 double]
[1×5 double]
[1×4 double]
```

Use a for loop to display the contents of the cell array C.

```
for i = 1:length(C)
    disp(C{i});
end

 9     2     1     8
 8     1     6     5     7
 6     1     2     4
 6     4     3     5
10     3     5     7
10     3     4     2     9
10     7     8     9
```

One of the cell is `9 2 1 8`. It means the vertices of this cell is `V(9,:), V(2,:), V(1,:), V(8,:)` respectively.